# JSON: get item by ID

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON of something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_ID": "3",
        "dash_title": "some title",
        "dash_description": "some description"
    },
    {
        "_ID": "2",
        "dash_title": "some title",
        "dash_description": "some description"
    },
    {
        "_ID": "1",
        "dash_title": "some title",
        "dash_description": "some description"
    }
]
```

I need to get all the objects and display only the first and third from the bottom. Now I do this simply by using the object's ordinal number, like this:

```
function _dashboard_clients_info() {

    $url     = 'some JSON URL';
    $request = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );

    $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    $data = json_decode( $html );
    
    $head =  $data[2];
    $foot =  $data[0];

    if( ! empty( $head->dash_description ) ) {
        echo wpautop( '<div class="dash_head">' . $head->dash_description . '</div>' );
        echo $head->html_css_js;
    } else { };

    if( ! empty( $foot->dash_description ) ) {
        echo wpautop( '<div class="dash_foot">' . $foot->dash_description . '</div>' );
        echo $foot->html_css_js;
    } else { };

}
```

The problem is that if an object is added to JSON, then the sequence number of the first object from the bottom also changes. But the object ID remains the same.

I would like to iterate through all the IDs in this JSON and pass in `$head` `id=1`, `$foot` `id=3`.

I will be grateful for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `$data` is an array of objects and every object id is unique, you can use the `array_filter` function to search for an entry with a specific id.

```
$head = current(array_filter($data, function($current) {
    return $current->_ID == 1;
}));

$foot = current(array_filter($data, function($current) {
    return $current->_ID == 3;
}));
```

Beware: If the array conaints more than one object with the same id only the first found object will be returned.

Comment: thank you for this hint, everything worked stably, but recently an error appeared «Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...». Although nothing has changed for me. Еhe erroneous string is shown on the closing brackets }));

Comment: Have you debugged `$data` before filtering it? Try a `var_dump($data)` and check, if the `json_decore` call is errornous or if the expected array structure could be retrieved. Seems like `$data` is not the expected array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I found the problem)